# iOS background sprite not displaying

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, background-image

I have a tricky little bug on my hands.

Consider [this page](http://tinycouchbigconcepts.com/our-process/). The [images that accompany the paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DJjc.jpg) are all called from a sprite, and as the viewport scales down, different background-positions are called to accomodate the various layouts in the responsive design.

In browser testing, all views/devices provide no serious bugs for all devices/browsers aside from IE<9…and [iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuVlM.jpg)([accompanying inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtcxG.jpg)). It's seeming that somehow iOS *devices* (the same view/width displays correctly on desktop) are for some reason, not displaying anything in those divs. Inspector throws no errors, and the network timers show that the sprite did indeed load.

To thicken the plot, I'm able to load the sprite in iOS safari if I call the direct URL. Perms are set to 755 on all image assets, and I've tried using various dom elements (div, span, p, i) and background techniques (namely including a `&nbsp;` in the `<div>`, declaring `content: '';` and conversely `content: ' ';`);

I've tested this on Mac/Win Chrome/Firefox/Safari, Android devices, iPhone4/5 and iPad (iOS6). The devices that are not displaying (at least on my hardware) the background divs are the iPhones and iPads.

Anyone have insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in mobile Safari that makes it so CSS background images with total resolutions larger than 2,000,000 pixels do not display at all. A [blog post from 2010](http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/) explores this in depth. As far as I know, it was never rectified. To get the background image to show up, you'll need to make it smaller (in terms of total pixels) or break it into two or more sprites. I've definitely seen this happen before; the only fix was to make the images smaller. Not in file size, in pixels.

Comment: That's a fun little bug. I knew I had a massive sprite, but I wasn't aware it would make iOS balk.

Answer (score 1):

Cute site.

The issue is that your Tiny Couch is housing a freakishly enormous sprite. Although it only comes in a a little over 300kb (still pretty big) it might be the dimensions that mean it can't be processed - I've never seen this before though so I could be mistaken.

I love the ideas of trying to serve things with the sprite meaning that there's only one http request, but in this case the bottom part of your sprite will only ever get called when viewing on a mobile device. It might be worth breaking it out into a desktop sprite and a mobile sprite and then loading them in with the appropriate media queries.

The reason

Comment: I thought iOS might be choking on the sprite itself, but I'm able to load the image if I call it directly in the browser. Do you think moving the mobile images to the top of the sprite would solve anything, or is it just the image's sheer mass that's causing the issue?

Comment: I think your best to split it out to be honest, even at the top of the file it still doesn't seem to render as a background.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up moving the sprite into desktop and mobile. It makes more sense anyway as this way mobile is required to load much less in way of assets.

Answer (score 0):

The limit seems to be different in different cases.
I'm testing on a iPhone 4 device with iOS 5.1.1,
and the limit of the file itself doesn't seem as important than 
the background size. 
If I use a background 1100px X 1000px it will not work.
But if I set background-size to 1000px X 1000px it will work.

So if I use a High DPI(2x) version, 2000px X 2000px and set image-size
to 1000px X 1000px it will still work, even though the background itself is bigger.

So it's recommended to use 1000px X 1000px for your default sprite,
and then you can have at least a 2xDPI. Haven't tried 3x.